# General expression for a Scalar Superfield with ${\cal N = 1}$ in $D = 10$

Tags: supersymmetry, supergravity, superspace-formalism

I need to write explicitly the most general form of a scalar superfield in 10 dimensions up to second order in grassman variables $\theta^\alpha$. I know that up to first order one can write

\begin{equation}
S(x, \theta) = s(x) + \theta^\alpha \chi_\alpha(x) + \mathcal{O}(\theta^2)
\end{equation}

where s is a scalar and $\chi_\alpha$ is a spinor. But I begin to have some problems when I try to write the next order. I tried writing it as

\begin{equation}
S(x, \theta) = s(x) + \theta^\alpha \chi_\alpha(x) + \theta^\alpha \theta^\beta D_{\alpha \beta} + \mathcal{O}(\theta^3)
\end{equation}

where $D_{\alpha \beta}$ is a bispinor.

Due to the fact that $\theta^\alpha \theta^\beta = -\theta^\beta \theta^\alpha$, it would mean that $D_{\alpha \beta} = D_{[\alpha \beta]}$ (and that $D_{\alpha \beta}$ is an antisymmetric bispinor).

It would also mean that one could not encounter symmetric bispinor field content in a scalar superfield in 10 dimensions (at least up to that order). Is the way I wrote the second order correct? If it is, I would like to know the constraints (if any) on the bispinor content in the second order.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true. More known and simple example of such situation is 4d chiral superfied. In such situation we have only $\theta^\alpha$, $\alpha=1,2$. So scalar superfied:

$$
\Phi =\phi + \theta^\alpha \chi_\alpha +\theta^2 D
$$

Due to antisymetrisation, we have scalar superfied in highest power on $\theta$. I used $D_{[\alpha\beta]} \propto\epsilon_{\alpha\beta}D$.